# Regular expression for adding character at the end if not found

Tags: php, regex

I am storing routine time in the database table as `4-6;6-7`. Now I want to parse it and display in following format. I can do it using multiple explodes with loops. But I think it can be done with regex. I want the output to look like this:

If data is `4-6;6-7` then output should be like:

```
 4:00 - 6:00
 6:00 - 7:00
```

If data is `4:30-6:30;6-7:30` then output should be like:

```
 4:30 - 6:30
 6:00 - 7:30
```

Comment: yes I want it to do in regex.

Answer (score 1):

Not regex but same result: (love `explode`-ing some shits)

```
<?php
$str = '4-6;6-7';

$two_t = explode(';',$str);
$first_t = explode('-',$two_t[0]);
$second_t = explode('-',$two_t[1]);

$time = setMinutes($first_t[0]) .'-'.setMinutes($first_t[1]) ."<br/>". setMinutes($second_t[0]) .'-'. setMinutes($second_t[1]);
echo $time;

function setMinutes($time){
    $quarter = explode(':',$time);
    $hour = $quarter[0];
    if(!isset($quarter[1])){
        $minutes = '00';
    }else{
        $minutes = $quarter[1];
    }
    return "$hour:$minutes";
}
?>
```

output:

```
4:00-6:00
6:00-7:00
```

**UPDATED**

As requested, using regular expression:

```
$str = '4:30-6:30;6-7:30';
echo formatTime($str);

echo "\n\n";

$str = '4-6;6-7';
echo formatTime($str);


function formatTime($str) {
    // get all match per group separating each time and minute
    preg_match_all('/(\d(:\d\d)?)-(\d(:\d\d)?);(\d(:\d\d)?)-(\d(:\d\d)?)/', $str, $matches);

    // remove the whole match
    unset($matches[0]);

    // loop through the matches and check if minutes(in even keys) exists
    foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
        if ($key % 2 == 0) {
            $matches[$key - 1][0] = (strlen($value[0]) == 0) ? $matches[$key - 1][0] . ':00' : $matches[$key - 1][0];
        }
    }

    // combine all the time in odd keys
    return $matches[1][0] . '-' . $matches[3][0] . "\n" . $matches[5][0] . '-' . $matches[7][0];
}
```

output:

```
4:30-6:30
6:00-7:30

4:00-6:00
6:00-7:00
```

Comment: Thank you. I would be nice if it can be done with regex.

Comment: @user254153 I do not have time yesterday but i'll try today

Answer (score 1):

you can access any pattern-groups through using (?<'NAME'> SUB_PATTERN).
The result is an array that contains the 'NAME' index.

```
<?php

$date = "4:30-6:30;6-7:30";
// $date = "4-6;6-7";
$result = '';
$pattern = '/^(?<a>.*)-(?<b>.*);(?<c>.*)-(?<d>.*)$/';
preg_match($pattern , $date , $matches);


$pattern2 = '/^\s*((?<h2>\d+)|(?<h1>\d+:\d+))\s*$/';

preg_match($pattern2 , $matches['a'] , $match);
$result .= ((isset($match['h1'])) ? $match['h1'] : $match['h2'].':00');
$result .= ' - ';
preg_match($pattern2 , $matches['b'] , $match);
$result .= ((isset($match['h1'])) ? $match['h1'] : $match['h2'].':00');

$result .=  '<br />';

preg_match($pattern2 , $matches['c'] , $match);
$result .= ((isset($match['h1'])) ? $match['h1'] : $match['h2'].':00');
$result .= ' - ';
preg_match($pattern2 , $matches['d'] , $match);
$result .= ((isset($match['h1'])) ? $match['h1'] : $match['h2'].':00');


echo $result;
```

Comment: @winner_joiner more explanation is added.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the replace function?
str_replace("-",":",$string);
str_replace(";"," - ",$string);

Comment: It would not give what I wanted.

Comment: And something like that?  
preg_replace('/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)(\;)?/g', '$1:$2', $str); Catch digits and replace special characters by whatever you want.